# How do I filter a filtered DataGridView [VB 2010 Express / MS Access]

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

So how do I filter a DataGridView that has already been filtered?

I have a table named "tbl_att" that contains the following columns: id_num, att_date, status.

In my form, there is a textbox (txt_studnum) that filters the student number (id_num). The code is:

```
    Private Sub viewatt_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    provider2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile2 = "C:\DATABASE\rams.accdb" 
    connString2 = provider2 & dataFile2
    myConnection2.ConnectionString = connString2
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [IDNum], [att_date], [status] from tbl_att", myConnection2)
    da.Fill(ds, "tbl_att")


    Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
    DataGridView1.Refresh()

    End Sub
```

And the execute event for this is by clicking a button:

```
Private Sub btn_search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_search.Click

 source1.Filter = "[IDnum] = '" & txt_idnumber.Text & "' "

End Sub
```

What happens is, the user will input the ID number, clicks the button and the DataGridView (DataGridView1) will display the filtered results.

What I want to do is to filter the already filtered data in DGV1 by using a combobox that will filter "status". This combobox will have "Present", "Absent" and "Late" as items, which corresponds to the data inside the "status" column.

I tried making another button for filtering status using:

```
source1.Filter = "[status] = '" & cmb_status.Text & "' "
```

But the DGV displays all the Present, Absent or Late regardless of ID number. Hope anyone can help me with this. I apologize for the bad english as well. Thanks!

Comment: Obviously - you need to combine your filters of your dataview like , `filter = "[status] = '{0}' AND [IDnum] = '{1}' "` Then you use `source1.Filter = string.Format(filter,...` BTW, is your `IDnum` a string?

Comment: So, you didn't think the solution above was The solution? `string.format` is much cleaner than endless concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For second filter use:

```
source1.Filter = "[IDnum] = '" & txt_idnumber.Text & "'  AND [status] = '" & cmb_status.Text & "' "
```